# ¿Como modificar un dataframe con shiny en el que añadas una columna en la cual puedas introducir manualmente texto?

Tags: rstudio, shiny

Tengo este código en el que se carga un archivo csv y lo que quiero es generar una tabla cuando le des al botón go en la que aparezca los datos del archivo csv cargado y se añada una columna con el valor que se introduzca en el campo texto. He probado con esto pero no se genera la tabla. Como no me deja publicar todo el código, pongo las partes que tengo problemas.

Tengo declaradas estas funciones dentro del UI de shiny:

```
fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")),
actionButton("go", "Go"),
textInput("text", "text")
```

Y en el server:

```
  server <- function(input, output) {


  output$contents <- renderTable({



  req(input$file1)



   randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
   input$text %>% cbind(input%>%file1)
   })

   output$table <- renderTable({
   randomVals()
   })
```

Comment: Hola María, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola! Cuando intento añadir mi código me aparece lo siguiente y no me deja publicarlo: Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.

Comment: Has una pequeña introducción, contando cual es el problema, no importa que se repita.